# CompletableFuture long running task with time out would it hold thread given composed with timeout future?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

In the following code intention is to achieve asynchronous execution of a task provided it runs in less than 100 ms else timeout exception from other thread would be thrown ,

**Question**  : What happens to the thread that is executing asynchronously for more than 100 ms , would it be released ? or it would wait for the task to complete without throwing exception ? ( wrote the code thinking that acceptEither would terminate the long running task once it encounters the timeOutException from the other future)

```
private static final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> failAfter(long longValue) {
        final CompletableFuture<T> timeoutFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        scheduler.schedule(() -> {
            final TimeoutException ex = new TimeoutException("Timing out");
            return timeoutFuture.completeExceptionally(ex);
        }, longValue, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return timeoutFuture;
    }  

final CompletableFuture<CustomResponse> CustomResponseFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> object.taks()).
                exceptionally(ex -> {
                    System.out.println("help");
                    return new "Hello";
                    });

        CustomResponseFuture
        .acceptEither(failAfter(100l), TesFutureStuff::myNewMethod)
        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
            System.out.println("failure "+throwable.getMessage());
             return null;
        })/*.getNow(null )*/;
```

Comment: Creating a task that can time out does not need all this complexity.  Just create an ExecutorService, and call its [invokeAny](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny(java.util.Collection,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) method.

Comment: @VGR thank you , could you pls let me know how could i acheive that using completable future , wanted to try it out using java 8 jargon

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a task that terminates after a specific amount of time, you don’t need CompletableFuture.  Just [create an ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()), and call its [invokeAny](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny(java.util.Collection,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) method.

If you insist on using CompletableFuture, you can use its [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) and [cancel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#cancel(boolean)) methods:

```
CompletableFuture<CustomResponse> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> object.task());
try {
    CustomResponse response = future.get(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    // process response here
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    future.cancel(true);
}
```

**Update:**

To do the whole thing in the background, submit the invokeAny call to the same ExecutorService, but make sure the ExecutorService is not single threaded.  There are many choices: [Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29), [Executors.newWorkStealingPool()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newWorkStealingPool%28%29), [Executors.newCachedThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29), or even [ForkJoinPool.commonPool()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool%28%29).

For the CompletableFuture approach, I just noticed that as of Java 9, CompletableFuture adds an [orTimeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#orTimeout%28long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method:

```
future.orTimeout(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: But the call to the get() is blocking right , so my whole point of view is to avoid it actually.

Comment: Updated answer.  I hadn’t realized that many new methods were added to CompletableFuture when Java 9 was released…